# Framer-motion - 2 step animation

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

Imagine i have a button, when clicking on it, a red box appears and slides to right (simplified for explanation):

```js
const [start, setStart] = useState(false);

return (
  <>
    <button onClick={() => setStart(true)}>Animate it</button>
    {start && (
      <motion.div
        className='w-20 h-20 bg-red-500'
        initial={{ x: 0 }}
        animate={{ x: 400 }}
      />
    )}
  </>
);
```

But what i want is that it first scales up and then slides to right (this is what i mean by saying 2 step animation)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Define Keyframes

An easy way to your question is setting [keyframes](https://www.framer.com/docs/animation/##keyframes) for your `animate` props.

```js
animate={{ x: [0, 0, 0, 400], scale: [0, 1, 1, 1] }}
```

Basically, I have 4 keyframes with 2 properties of `x` and `scale`:

| Frame | Animation values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 (initial frame) | x: 0; scale: 0 |
| 2 | x: 0; scale: 1 |
| 3 | x: 0; scale: 1 |
| 4 | x: 400; scale: 1 |

Working demo available on [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-glade-cr6ocx)